# How to find average datetime in a object?

Tags: python, django

I created an approval system. I have an `ApprovalProcess` model. This model has `end_date` and `begin_date`. And end_date - beginning_date is duration time. I have several ApprovalProcess models I want to find what is the total average duration time of all ApprovalProcess objects. I cannot find the difference between end_date and begin_date. It gives an error:

> TypeError at /approval/logs unsupported operand type(s) for -:
> 'NoneType' and 'datetime.datetime'

How can I do it?

**models.py**

```
class ApprovalProcess(models.Model):
    ...
    begin_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    ...
```

**views.py**

```
def log_records(request):
...
approval_list = ApprovalProcess.objects.filter(user_id=request.user)
delta = 0
    approval_list = ApprovalProcess.objects.filter(customer__company=request.user.company)
    for approval_object in approval_list:
        delta = abs((approval_object.end_date - approval_object.begin_date).days)
...
```

**traceback**

```
   Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/approval/logs

Django Version: 3.1.4
Python Version: 3.8.8
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'register',
 'customer',
 'financial_analysis',
 'ocr',
 'core',
 'approvals',
 'crispy_forms',
 'ckeditor',
 'rest_framework',
 'requests',
 'ckeditor_uploader',
 'django_filters',
 'activity_log',
 'djmoney',
 'djmoney.contrib.exchange']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\approvals\views.py", line 501, in log_records
    delta = abs((approval_object.end_date - approval_object.begin_date).days)

Exception Type: TypeError at /approval/logs
Exception Value: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

Comment: Error mentions the operator: "+" not the "-" which you used for computing difference. Can you check the line number mentioned in the error.

Comment: can you post full error trace back

Comment: @c.grey I added.

Comment: There is some `ApprovalProcess` instance where `end_date` is null. Hence you get the error.

Comment: It is because `approval_object.end_date` is evaluating to `None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  can filter when end_date is None in the query:.

`approval_list = ApprovalProcess.objects.filter(user_id=request.user).exclude(end_date=None)`

Answer (score 1):

try this

for update question.

```
if approval_object.end_date and approval_object.begin_date:
    delta = abs((approval_object.end_date - approval_object.begin_date).days)

#duration = duration + (review.end_date - review.begin_date).days
```

Comment: I paste the wrong traceback and I edited it can you look again please, I'm sorry for that